# COP and input work in a refrigerator

Tags: thermodynamics, work, cooling

Where can i find a COP and input work requierd in a standard modern refrigerator? I need a sample refrigerator, so that I can calculate the heat disposed to the surrounding and use that to design an heat exchanger.

Comment: That totally depends on the refrigerator. There is no such thing as a "standard" refrigerator. There are small inefficient ones and there are large efficient ones. The only thing you can do is to get the fridge that you want and then you measure how much heat it produces in your application. A modern household refrigerator uses approx. 400-600kWh per year... so that's the least you have to deal with.

Comment: You will find a representative calculation with references to a paper showing detailed measurements [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/230465/26969)